# Ajax takes 10x as long as it should/could

Tags: ajax, performance

I have just hit my first serious issue with WordPress and for someone that enjoys Ajax this is a biggy.

I have an Ajax request that is taking 1.5 seconds to complete while using the Ajax API.

If I take the same exact code and run it with a custom script(no WordPress) the Ajax request takes merely 150 milliseconds. **This is not an exaggeration**

If you look at the very first comment of http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/ and the conversation that follows you will see that this slowness is caused by the fact that on your request, all of WP is loaded...

I am hoping that there is a solution out there that will make it possible to make Ajax requests while not loading all of WordPress.

What are your experiences with speeding up Ajax requests with WordPress?

Comment: I wonder wether popular caching plugins cover this situation.

Comment: @Raphael, I thought about that too, but have not seen any mention of it. That would be GREAT if they do

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yep, this is nasty issue that to have full WordPress environment you need to spend considerable time loading it.

I've needed much better performance (for very dynamic incremental search feature) for work and what I went with is:

1. Custom file as Ajax handler.
2. [SHORTINIT constant](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.6/wp-settings.php#L94) for limited WP core load.
3. Very selectively loaded parts of core, only those needed for the task.

This provides very limited environment, but performance is way way better and reasonable degree of compatibility with WP (starting with `$wpdb`) is retained.

Here is start my loader file, not pretty but works for specific needs:

```
<?php

ini_set('html_errors', 0);
define('SHORTINIT', true);

require '../../../../wp-load.php';
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php' );
wp_plugin_directory_constants();

// stuff goes here
```

Comment: What do you mean by SHORTINIT contant? Can you provide examples? I envision that I will need to set up my own handlers with varying degrees of WP loaded depending on the need of the request, but I would like to see some examples you have created.

Comment: @Mike it's not widely known but really simple in concept - [if `SHORTINIT` constant is set](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.3/wp-settings.php#L98) WP would not load most of the core (no most of APIs/functions, no plugins, no theme). I will add some code to answer.

Comment: That looks ok. I just dont like the fact that we have to use require '../../../../wp-load.php'; that makes this pretty custom. I also worry how easy it is to actually pull in the resources you "need", b/c from my experience WordPress is not very modular.

Comment: @Mike correct, but even with issues it's much better than endpoint that has no clue about WP at all. This can (and should) be improved some more but it's not urgent task for me at moment.

Comment: Are there any methods of detecting the location of the wp-load.php from within WordPress?  For example, could I write a static file with the path set as a variable within it on plugin load, then include that file in the stand alone Ajax response file?

Comment: @hereswhatidid yes, that is one of the options, you could use PHP's `get_included_files()` for example. However note that writing to plugin's dir is not-so-good practice, typically filesystem writes should only go to content directory. This is kind of issue that is not that challenging to configure for yourself, but is quite difficult to produce solution that is appropriate for public code.

Comment: @Rarst, instead of `require '../../../../wp-load.php';` I think is better using something like:`$dir = explode ( 'wp-content', dirname(__FILE__) );` and so `require $dir[0] . 'wp_load.php'`? I think it's more flexible and can be used everywhere in theme or plugin

Comment: @G.M. content folder can be freely relocated, it is wrong assumption that code runs from inside core directory. As above - this is challenging to handle in generic way.

Comment: @Rarst, for sure content folder can be relocated, but if so your soluction *can* also fail, or I'm wrong? If in my plugin (or theme) I have a `options.php` file where I `define('WPCONTENTROOTFOLDER', 'wp-content')` and then `$dir = explode ( WPCONTENTROOTFOLDER, dirname(__FILE__) )` this will work 90% of times, for the rest I write in my plugin docs what change if content folder is moved. E.G. I can implement another constant 'FULLWPCONTENTFOLDER', normally empty but if setted plugin will use this one, instead.

Comment: @G.M. my solution is specific to my install, it's not meant for distributable code. Your code is merely hardcoding different (more generic _relatively_, I agree) assumption, but personally I don't think it's up to distributable code level either

Comment: @Rarst (last thing, I swear) Yes, probably mine is not *distributable* code, (sure not in WP repository and/or for large target), but I think is *reusable* code, even only for myself: at this time I have more than 20 clients WP installations online and in all of these the are plugins developed by myself, so write easy reusable code is vital for me even if not for distributable code.

Comment: I've been using a forked (private) version of this plugin found on GitHub: http://github.com/EkAndreas/ajaxflow/

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it sped up my ajax.

```
function my_deregister_heartbeat() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow ) {
         wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
         wp_register_script('heartbeat', false);
     }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_heartbeat' );
```