# Adding wp_ajax to a theme outside functions.php (on specific template page)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing a function which requires the use of the `wp_ajax` action.

I've followed [this guide](http://stv.whtly.com/2011/09/12/using-front-end-ajax-requests-in-your-wordpress-plugins/) to set it up with the differences of adding the requesting the object AJAX file in functions.php and also added

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    do_action('wp_ajax_'.$_REQUEST['action']);
    do_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_'.$_REQUEST['action']);
}
```

to make it work.

Issue is that obviously having the file in functions.php causes every page to initialise workflow, but I only want it on one particular template file.

I could add it as a plugin I'm aware, but certain functions used are global to the theme and will never be used on any other theme so doesn't make sense in my mind to do that.

Ideally, I would just like to do `require('ajax_file.php');` in the template file, but that's the main issue here is I don't think I can (unless somebody can correct me). So if there is an easy way to call it from the functions.php file without every other page also calling it then that would be a massive help.

Thanks!

Comment: Aware that I could use `$_SERVER` to detect the page but if the URL changes then it's case of diving back into the code to fix it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Just to clarify:

`add_action('wp_ajax_<action>', 'do_my_action');`
followed by a 
`do_action('wp_ajax_<action>');`

is same as calling `do_my_action`. Do you really need ajax for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop it in a plugin. Theme = view. Plugin = constructor. I keep most of my stuff in plugins. IMHO only stuff that belongs to the visual part should be in the Theme. And yes, you can do a simple `require( plugin_dir_path( $file_name ) );` for subfiles.

Comment: The issue is this method doesn't work with the flow of the project. Though, working through the problem I'm thinking this might be required, just annoying with the overheads of adding another plugin and to what level the separation needs to be done keep in mind this AJAX is core to the theme. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Note #1: I assume, that you´re simply doing AJAX in a non-WP fashion. Which is not recommended. Just read through [tag:ajax] to see if you´re doing it right. Note #2: In WP there´s  no actual "file workflow". You have hooks which are guiding your workflow. Use a plugin, load your dependencies, hook where you need it, use conditional tags to route on public and use globals and hooks on admin UI pages to determine if you´re  where you want to be.

Comment: It's difficult to give full details on the project so it's a little confusing to explain what the flow is I'm talking about (more internal policy rather than WP). But this is using the correct AJAX method unless the method I described in the question is incorrect (`wp_ajax` and `wp_localize_script`) - I've done the whole `../../wp_load.php` before and it's too buggy. I've been evaluating and debugging it a bit more and some other spanners have hit the works so it looks as if I have to do it as a plugin that's dependent on a theme. :/

Comment: Plugin/MU-Plugin/Theme makes _exactly no_ difference. The only difference is the place where you save it inside the WP dir struct. 1st) Go and use `admin-ajax.php` and the default way of using [tag:ajax] 2nd) Get it running. 3rd) [Take a look at this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41812/385), when you got a working solution. This might help you to shorten the init time, depending on what you need from the WP env.