# Create a short code that inserts js

Tags: jquery, shortcode

**Note:** People are assuming this question is already answered when in fact it is no where close to being the right answer.

I have created tons of short codes, How ever I am using [Jquery plugin TOC](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/5-jquery-table-content-toc-plugins/) and I would like to create a short code for it, I am not sure where to begin. I would assume you would follow standard procedure for creating one, but I have never had one spit out javascript before.

The only code I have to show you is, my short code:

```
if(! function_exists ('aisis_toc') ){
    function aisis_toc($atts, $content = null){
        return '
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function(){ $("#toc").tableOfContents(); })
        </script>';
    }
}
```

I have registered the hort code as toc, and tried doing `[toc]` but alas nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I don't need or shouldn't need ajax of any kind. this should be easy.

I should also state that this short code should only get the h1-6 tags that are in the post them selves and not on the page in general.

Comment: See also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73009/73

Comment: no thats not what I want.

Comment: Please explain why you cannot return a string with your JavaScript and why you have to use an inline-script at all.

Comment: I can see this scenario. You would enqueue the library but still need to run `jQuery.do_stuff(some, parameters);` I would consider an inline script to be preferable to enqueueing another file, for that case.

Comment: @toscho UPDATED THE POST. Check it out. theres your code sample.

Comment: Reopened, but I still see no difference to the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script into an external file, set the selector there and enqueue it from your shortcode:

```
if(! function_exists ('aisis_toc') )
{
    function aisis_toc() 
    {
        if ( ! is_singular() )
            return;

        wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery-toc',
        plugins_url( 'js/jquery-toc.js', __FILE__ ),
        array ( 'jquery' ),
        NULL,
        TRUE);

        return;
    }
}
```