# Get shortcode attributes outside shortcode function

Tags: shortcode

I'm writing a slideshow shortcode and need to grab the shortcode attributes in an external function so I can add the javascript to the footer.

For example:

```
add_shortcode('test','test_function');
function test_function($atts) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'arrows' => true,
    ), $atts));

    return '..............';
}
```

Now I want to pass the "arrows" attribute into the javascript which I want to include in the footer..

```
function add_slideshow_js() { ?>
    <script>
        jQuery("ID").slideshow({
            directionNav : <?php echo $arrows; ?>
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer','add_slideshow_js');
```

Of course, this is just a very simplistic version..

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array to your script with `wp_localize_script($handle, $object_name, $l10n)`.

```
function test_function( $atts )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        array (
            'arrows' => TRUE
        ),
        $atts
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script_name' );
    wp_localize_script(
        'your_script_name',
        'yourScriptObject',
        $data
    );

    return 'a string';
}
```

In your (external) script you can access the shortcode data now with …

```
var arrows = yourScriptObject.arrows;
```

… because WordPress will create a global accessible JavaScript with the name `yourScriptObject` now before it loads your external script.

Further shortcode attributes are available with `yourScriptObject.othername` or whatever the names are that you are using. For a more detailed example see my script in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73009/73).

Comment: Thanks for the code! Couple questions.. My shortcode has about 20 attributes (not just "arrows") - does that mean I have to set up the 20 different vars in the external script? And what exactly is the "yourScriptObject" referring to? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom See my update, I tried to explain it better.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Please forgive me as I'm not well versed in javascript (at all), but then in my script, would I do something like this: http://pastebin.com/ui99T202 - or am I WAY off?

Comment: @Tom Looks already very good. :) Now try it.

Comment: No luck, I'm receiving an error: Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array. Here's my PHP: http://pastebin.com/EsH6PDwu and the pro-slideshow.js file: http://pastebin.com/73ja1ShN. Thanks for any guidance you can give me! :)

Comment: The data are before the .js file in my page, no access to data

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was create a global array with the attributes I needed in the external function. Then I simply called that global in my external function, and called all of the values like so: $slideshow_data['arrows'] etc.. Worked like a charm :)

So for example:

```
global $slideshow_data;
$slideshow_data = array(
    'id'     => $id,
    'arrows' => $arrows,
);
```

This above code goes inside the actual shortcode function.

Then inside my add_slideshow_js function, I did this:

```
global $slideshow_data;
?>
<script>
jQuery("<?php echo $slideshow_data['id'];?>").slideshow({
    directionNav : <?php echo $slideshow_data['arrows']; ?>
});
</script>
<?php.....
```

The only problem with this is I can't have more than one slideshow per page.. If anyone has any ideas on that I would be very grateful!