# wp_localize_script not passing the data

Tags: plugins, shortcode, wp-localize-script

I've been trying to work with a small plugin and I tried to pass my data to js via `wp_localize_script` but when I'm doing `console.log()` inside my js it is returning `undefined`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here:

```
$shortcode_data = array();

/*Fetching the plugin directoryt path*/
$dir = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

// Let's create the before after shortcode First
add_shortcode('before_after', function( $atts ) {
    //extracting the shortcode attributes
    global $shortcode_data;
    $shortcode_data = shortcode_atts( array(
        'slide' => 5, // max 7
        'src1_org' => null,
        'src1_new' => null,
        'src2_org' => null,
        'src2_new' => null
    ), $atts );

    extract($shortcode_data);

    //... do my work with the variables

});

//Let's include the CSS & JS scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    global $dir;
    global $shortcode_data;

    /*CSS*/
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style', $dir . 'assets/css/custom.css', null, null );

    /*JS*/
    wp_register_script ('custom_script', $dir . 'assets/js/custom.js');
    wp_localize_script( 'custom_script', 'ismSliderData', $shortcode_data ); // this line supposed to send all of my shortcode variables to the js but it is not doing that
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script', true );
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, your shortcode will be executed after [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) -- when the post content is output. That's why the data isn't available to your scripts during [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

`wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )`

You would;

**A**) Need to gather your shortcode attributes ahead of time.

**B**) Put your custom script in the footer and output `<script>` data during the shortcode's output.

**C**) Put your custom script in the footer and output inline js during [`wp_print_footer_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_footer_scripts/). You may need to wrap your custom scripts in closures to execute after localize has been added.

**D**) Locallize during the shortcode

---

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97285/84219) is an example of localizing during the shortcode:

```
function some_shortcode( $atts )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        array (
            'arrows' => TRUE
        ),
        $atts
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script_name' );

    wp_localize_script(
        'your_script_name',
        'yourScriptObject',
        $data
    );

    return 'a string of whatever';
}
```

Comment: So, whats the solution then?

Comment: Can you share a small snippet about how you are suggesting me to do that?

Comment: I thought about putting inline js but it doesn't seem a good approach. So if you have any idea about how can I access my shortcode variables in localize script, it would be really help if you could post a small snippet for that.

Comment: Yah! I've taken the exact same option and it worked. thanks.

Comment: I've registered my script inside shortcode too

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/