# Why is my ajax live search not working when i use a shortcode to call it?

Tags: shortcode, ajax

I've finally managed to get my live search in Wordpress working, but it only works when i directly call it in the class.

I want to put it in a shortcode, so i can call it on every page i want. But when i call the shortcode, my jquery/ajax is not working.

**Constructor**

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_schoenen_zoeken_shortcode_output', array($this, 'schoenen_zoeken_shortcode_output'));
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_schoenen_zoeken_shortcode_output', array($this, 'schoenen_zoeken_shortcode_output'));
    add_action( 'wp_head', array($this, 'add_js' ));
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'register_schoenen_shortcodes'));
```

**Javascript:**

```
    public function add_js() {
      ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

**Shortcode**

```
 public function register_schoenen_shortcodes() {

       add_shortcode('schoenen_zoeken', array($this, 'schoenen_zoeken_shortcode_output'));

    }
```

**PHP AND HTML**

```
  public function schoenen_zoeken_shortcode_output() {
        global $wpdb;      

        if ($_POST) {
        $q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
        foreach ($wpdb->get_results("SELECT plaatsen FROM wp_plaatsen WHERE plaatsen LIKE '%$q%'") as $key => $row) {

            $plaatsnaam = $row->plaatsen;
            $b_plaatsnaam = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
            $final_plaatsnaam = str_ireplace($q, $b_plaatsnaam, $plaatsnaam);
?>
           <div class="show" align="left">
               <span class="name"><?php echo $final_plaatsnaam; ?></span>
</div>
<?php

        }
   die();

        }

        ?>
<div class="schoen_zoeken_container">
            <div class="schoen_zoeken">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                                <div class="zoeken">
                                <input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" name="search" placeholder="Zoek schoen" />
                                <div id="result">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the shortcode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use AJAX in shortcode](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72974/use-ajax-in-shortcode)

Answer (score 0):

Your ShortCode callback method should take an atts parameter that stores the attributes passed to it from the do_shortcode call which is I am assuming how you are getting the $q parameter for the database query.

The callback method should also return instead of echo the output.

Without seeing any of the output/error messages I would say you'll need to create a different method for the shortcode. Perhaps one that outputs the search form that will trigger the ajax calls.

Take a look a the [Shorcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for details on creating the callback.