# Display random text from a file with the WP built-in AJAX API

Tags: functions, shortcode, ajax

I want to use [a solution by @toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73009/25187) to display and rotate some quotes. The unchanged code works very well, but if I replace the

```
protected function get_rand()
{
    return rand( 1, 1000 );
}
```

with (from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72974/25187))

```
protected function get_rand()
{
    $array = file("wp-content/plugins/quotes-rotator/quotes.txt");
    $r = rand(0,count($array)-1);
    return $array[rand(0,count($array)-1)];
}
```

the code works well only at the first page load, but when I press the 'New' button to display a new quote the system outputs an error:

> Warning: file(wp-content/plugins/quotes-rotator/quotes.txt): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/quotes-rotator/ajax-shortcode-demo.php
>   on line 106

**What is wrong here?**

Comment: on the first page load, is the quote read throught the AJAX code or just with PHP ?

Comment: I think I found the answer in the other question : you use a file ajax-shortcode-demo.php for the AJAX call. I will write a answer to try to correct quickly your problem but I advice you to take time to avoid the use of this file and instead use the AJAX hook of WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to have the good path to the file, try this :

`$array = file(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "quotes.txt");`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now is OK! But what you mean by "... instead use the AJAX hook of WordPress"?

Comment: look these examples : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins