# Onclick want to call shortcode in wordpress

Tags: shortcode

I am new to wordpress custom page development.

I'm trying to show flowpaper pdf in my custom page.

This is the shortcut code

```
[flipbook pdf="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" lightbox="true" cover="" height="900"]
```

i want to show this on click.

```
<ul class="ul_items">
<li><a href="">one</a></li>
<li>two</li>
</ul>
```

i tried this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[flipbook pdf="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" lightbox="true" cover="" height="900"]'); ?>
```

but this is showing in page. :(

suggest me how can i achieve this on click of "one" it should appear.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72974/use-ajax-in-shortcode

Comment: nope .. but, for just to echo a shortcode, we have to develop this much code?

Comment: How does your shortcode code look like?

Comment: [flipbook pdf="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" lightbox="true" cover="" height="900"]
 it isin my poseted question

Comment: Create a popup and add that shortcode in the popup. On click of your link, open the popup, so now your Flipbook will be opened in the popup.