# Initialize class inside plugin

Tags: plugin-development

How can I initialize inside wordpress a class. I would like to send requests via ajax to plugins class. First I have the entry point.

```
class EntryClass{

    public function __construct()
    {
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this , 'wptuts_scripts_basic' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'podukt_konfigurator', array ($this, 'getProd_Config') );
    }

    function getProd_Config() { 
        ob_start();
        include( 'html/templ_config.php');
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $content;        
    }

    function wptuts_scripts_basic()
{
    // Register the script like this for a plugin:
    wp_register_script( 'konf-js', plugins_url( 'config.js', __FILE__ ) );
}

}

$init= new EntryClass();
```

The `templ_config.php` contains the Javascript which on event would load a php file inside of my plugin folder like

```
jQuery('#id').load(
            '/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/konfigurator/html/class.konfigurator.php',
            {
                prod_detail: jQuery(this).attr('rel')},
                function(msg){

                    show_driver(msg);
                }
                );
```

then in `class.konfigurator.php` I would like to use wordpress globals.

Comment: Firstly, you cannot just write javascript inside a PHP file. Secondly, to use wordpress globals, you just have to write `global $WP_VAR_NAME;` then you can work with it. Or use the 'shorthand' like `$GLOBALS['VAR_NAME']`.

Comment: I did not let me show you how. The problem is than I can not use for example $wpdb

Comment: Yes, you CAN use global WordPress variables. In your case it'd be `global $wpdb; $wpdb->WHATEVER;`. But I don't get the context of this and instantiating a class and all...

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't appear to have actually enqueued your script anywhere. You registered it, but don't [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it, unless that code is elsewhere.
2. When you load a file directly like you are-- aka., browsing straight to `'/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/konfigurator/html/class.konfigurator.php'`-- you can't use any of WordPress' functions because you have bypassed WordPress' boot process.

To use WordPress functions you need to load WordPress. In your case, to do that you should be using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), or if you need the performance, implement a solution like suggested [as an answer to AJAX API performance question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/ajax-takes-10x-as-long-as-it-should-could).

Comment: I don't know what the question has to do with initializing a class in a plugin though.