# Call to a member function get_row() on a non-object, Unable to use global $wbdp inside a plugin

Tags: php, wpdb

I am building a custom plugin for my WordPress site.

I made a php file called "checkrank" that obtains data from a custom table named "cranking".

```
$uid = $GET['id']; 

function checkExists($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cranking';
    $exists = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d" ) );

    $error = $wpdb->print_error();

    if(count($exists) > 0){
       echo 'Exists!';
    } else {
       echo 'Does not exist!';
    }

 return $error;
}

checkExists($uid);
```

The code is just to check whether the cranking table has the user with the provided ID.

The problem is, whenever i run this php file, i get this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function `get_row()` on a non-object

Where am I at fault here?
I think `$wbdp` is not initiated.

Comment: What do you mean by "whenever i run this php file"? Earlier, you mention that you are "building a custom plugin". Is this a plugin or a standalone file?

Comment: Hi,what i meant by running is going to the url (http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/checkrank.php?id=1

Comment: this is a php file inside my plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you clarify:

> what i meant by running is going to the url
>   (mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/checkrank.php?id=1)

In that case, you are running a standalone file.

Yes, one that resides inside WordPress' plugins folder, but you don't access it *in the context of WordPress* (i.e. from within it). Here, *none* of the WordPress core functions/methods/classes will be available, because they are simply never loaded.

Comment: thanks for replying, oh i see, I did ran using jquery ajax call, which also returns the same error. so how do I load the functions? or how should i actually test it?

Comment: thanks Johannes, i did some quick research, found my solution here:http://kynatro.com/blog/2012/12/11/finally-a-practical-use-for-wordpress-secret-shortinit-constant/

Comment: Yup, that is one of the approaches I was about to edit into the answer. Good find. As an aside, there is a multitude of answers on this stack detailing the same.

Comment: Here's [a good one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/ajax-takes-10x-as-long-as-it-should-could).