# how to use shortinit in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, performance

I want to load a minimal resources in Wordpress because the server that I'm working on is very slow.

I tried defining short init in the `wp-config` file:

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);
```

But then I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function main() on a non-object in /somepath/functions.php on line 790
```

So I tried adding this line on the uppermost portion of the plugin that I'm working with:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/load.php');
```

But it didn't work.

I tried putting it on the uppermost part of the plugin instead:

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
/*
Plugin Name: someplugin
*/
define('SHORTINIT', true);
```

But I get the following:

```
Notice: Constant SHORTINIT already defined in /someplugin/someplugin.php on line 9
```

Any ideas how to do this properly?

Comment: You need to define it before wordpress loads. [Have a look at this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41812/3094)