# Test if php document executed by Wordpress or directly

Tags: plugins, globals

Active plugin PHP files are interpreted automatically when you view a page, post, admin page, etc.

I could also run a plugin PHP directly if I knew the fully qualified URL, however it will most likely throw errors as non of the Wordpress functions will have been included.

How would I test if a plugins PHP page has been executed through Wordpress? Is there a global variable that is safe to rely on?

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if a plugin file has been loaded directly via a browser?

Comment: I am trying to process the code one way if it is executed via Wordpress and another way if I entered www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php

Comment: Why? Are you trying to implement an AJAX handler or form submission?

Comment: In this case... Yes I am

Comment: Then I ***strongly*** suggest you instead look at the WP AJAX api, you should never do what you're trying to do

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm perfectly agree that *normally* one should use ajax api, but that's so sloow, because of loading a bunch of things, and for very easy tasks directly loading a file for ajax request is IMHO a legit task. Sure not for plugins/themes to be shared/sold, but for own code it's not too bad things to do, and sometimes is lifesafer for high traffic sites.

Comment: then you should add an AJAX handler with SHORTINIT defined, else you're making assumptions about where your plugin is located etc, it's bad practice and there are better ways of getting around speed issues

Comment: @TomJNowell if you write code only for your own site and no one else **you know** where your plugin is located etc. Also, even using SHORTINIT WordPress load a bunch of files, fire a bunch of hooks, and perform some db queries: if ajax is used only to, just as example, got an array, load WP (even shortinited) isn't needed and overwhelming. Sure if you need full/a lot of WP you should use Ajax API, but sometimes you do ajax calls to do something that doesn't require WordPress or require just a function, and in high traffic sites, highly based on Ajax, require WP for that is a server nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never need to send a user or a form or an AJAX request directly to a plugin files URL.

**If you're submitting a form**, no new URL is needed at all, simply:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['formfield'] ) {
    // handle form submission and print thank you
} else {
    // display form
}
```

Or as most people do, use gravity forms or a plugin such as contact7

**If you're doing an AJAX call**, use the provided API for AJAX calls

PHP:

```
function example_ajax_request() {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
            $fruit = 'Apple';
        }
        echo $fruit;
    }
    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
   die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
    var fruit = 'Banana';
    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

### Notes on WP AJAX

- [Smashing Magazine How to use AJAX in WordPress](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)
- [A simple AJAX example](http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/)

The only time you should test if the file is being loaded as you requested, is so that you can immediatley exit the script to avoid security concerns.

E.g.

```
if ( !defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die();
}
```

### Faster AJAX calls

The standard AJAX caller can sometimes be under-performant when doing things on super high traffic sites, in this case, I defer to Rarsts answer here:

[Ajax takes 10x as long as it should/could](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/ajax-takes-10x-as-long-as-it-should-could)

But even in that case, I would not have a single file handle both the AJAX and the non-AJAX, it's poor separation of concerns. Your AJAX handler should be a separate dedicated file if it isn't using the WP AJAX APIs.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of way, you can look at a WordPress constant, or a WordPress function...

Examples:

#### Check for a constant

```
if ( defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
  // the constant WPINC is defined, so WordPress is loaded
  // you should not define a cosntant with this name... and if you absolutely need
  // you can use another WordPress specific constant, examples here:
  // http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_constants/index.html
}
```

#### Check for a function + hook fired

```
if ( function_exists('did_action') && did_action( 'muplugins_loaded' ) ) {
  // this check if did_action function exists and the muplugins_loaded is fired
  // if this is tru you can be pretty sure WordPress is loaded.
  // muplugins_loaded is the first hook fired by WP (before any regular plugin is loaded)
  // However if you define the constant SHORTINIT and set to a non-empty value
  // this will never be true
}
```