# AJAX – SHORTINIT set to TRUE returns blank

Tags: ajax, performance

Thought I'd take [this nifty shortinit trick](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/ajax-takes-10x-as-long-as-it-should-could/41812#41812) for a spin. However, when I include this in my custom ajax handler, I get no response from my callback. If I comment it, it works just fine. Anything changed?

```
<?php
//mimic the actual admin-ajax
define('DOING_AJAX', true);

if (!isset( $_POST['action']))
    die('-1');

ini_set('html_errors', 0);
define('SHORTINIT', true);
require_once('wp/wp-load.php'); 

//Typical headers
header('Content-Type: text/html');
send_nosniff_header();

//Disable caching
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');


$action = esc_attr(trim($_POST['action']));
$allowed_actions = array(
    'posts',
    'status',
);

if(in_array($action, $allowed_actions)){
    if(is_user_logged_in())
        do_action('handle_tumblr_'.$action);
    else
        do_action('handle_tumblr_nopriv_'.$action);
}
else{
    die('-1');
}
```

```
function tumblr_status() {
  echo 'whos there?';
  exit;
}

add_action('handle_tumblr_status','tumblr_status');
add_action('handle_tumblr_nopriv_status','tumblr_status');


function tumblr_posts() {
  echo 'k';
  exit;
}

add_action('handle_tumblr_posts','tumblr_posts');
add_action('handle_tumblr_nopriv_posts','tumblr_posts');
```

Comment: is it the `is_user_logged_in` that's causing problem? I tried putting a `die('hello');` before that check but it still came back blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `esc_attr()`, which isn't available if you use `define( 'SHORTINIT', true );` , see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.6/wp-settings.php#L95). So you either have to load the `formatting.php` manually or have to ditch the `define( 'SHORTINIT', true );` - actually like the example in the thread you are referring  to shows.

---

As said in the comment, I checked out mentally after the first function that can't work, but you are right about `do_action` - can't tell you exactly though what you need for that. Anyway, you should probably just not use `SHORTINIT` and won't have problems. Just to note as much, personally I just do my [AJAX tasks the Wordpress way](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Doh. Yeah, loaded up `formatting.php` and it seems to get me further. Seems `do_actions` is holding me up. I've included `plugin.php` and `pluggable.php` aswell, but it won't work, and from what I understand I shouldn't need more?

Comment: Using SHORTINIT gives you access to the database code and some of the multisite stuff, and that's about it. None of the core WordPress helpers will be loaded. If you need those helpers in any way, just don't use SHORTINIT.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I kind of checked out mentally after the first function that can't work. @INT Either make sure you load all you need or, like Otto said, don't use `SHORTINIT`.

Comment: I totally get that, going with `SHORTINIT` and require what's needed will make the ajax run faster though. Gonna see if I can located what's needed.

Comment: Sure, understood - you're likely not the only one interested in this, so just post the solution as answer. @INT

Comment: @INT mantain `SHORTINIT` is hard. You have to load all the thing you need, and all the things needed by the things that you need, and so on... Also, you need to check everithing works on every WordPress (major) update, because sometimes functions are moved from file to file (e.g. when deprecated, but not only in that case) and you can get fatal errors when before update everithing was fine. For same reason code may not work with older versions. Be careful with it and, just a tip, avoid to use it in plugin/themes to be shared or sold. Also, be sure to test your code with `WP_DEBUG` turned on.