# Ajax take too long to return code

Tags: ajax, performance

I'm bulding a new web site and I need use ajax to search and return some pages/post. I don't know the problem but my ajax need 2s or 3s to return the HTML structure with the page and some photos (this photos are for a slider).

In my ajax I return the HTML structure but it's a simple HTML (some divs, photos and the javascript to build the slider).

What can be the problem?

My ajax code is:

```
if ((!isset($_POST["miPost"])) || (!isset($_POST["slug"]))){
        echo "<p>Error.</p>";
        die();
    }
    //Buscamos los datos del post   
    $querySlider = array('category_name'=>'slider-'.$_POST["slug"],'order'=>"ASC");
    $objetoSlider = new WP_Query($querySlider); 
    if ($objetoSlider->have_posts()){
        ?>
        <div class="sliderSeccion-conoce">
            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider-conoce" class="nivoSlider">
                <?php
                    while($objetoSlider->have_posts()){
                        $objetoSlider->the_post();
                        if (has_post_thumbnail()){
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        }
                    }   
                ?>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php   
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>
    <?php 
        $queryDatos = array("cat"=>$_POST["miPost"]);
        $objetoDatos = new WP_Query($queryDatos);
        if ($objetoDatos->have_posts()){
        ?>
            <div class="contenido-conoce">
                <?php
                    while($objetoDatos->have_posts()){
                        $objetoDatos->the_post();                       
                        ?>
                        <div class="tituloContenido-conoce"><p><?php the_title();?></p></div>
                        <div class="textoContenido-conoce"><?php the_content();?></div>
                        <?php
                    }                   
                    if ($_POST["slug"]=="origenes"){
                        ?>
                        <a class="enlaceContenido-conoce" href="mysite" target="_blank">M&aacute;s informaci&oacute;n.</a>
                        <?php   
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php       
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#slider-conoce").nivoSlider({
                directionNav:true,
                effect:'fade',
                pauseTime: 4000,
                animSpeed:1000,
                slices:1
            });
            $("#contenido-conoceDerecha").show("fade");
        });
    </script>
    <?php   
    die();
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I try to insert some code like this (like the link who put in a comments):

```
define("SHORTINIT",0);
require 'wp-load.php';
require(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/formatting.php');
require(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/meta.php');
require(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/post.php');
```

But always give me some errors:

```
Notice: Constant SHORTINIT already defined.....

Constant ABSPATH already defined
```

This code has been write in the functions file or what can be construct a file to put all my ajax's functions (called to him, etc...)?

Comment: It is difficult to know seeing you code. How many posts are returned (slider + posts)? How big are the images? Aside recommendation: don't use `&aacute;`, `&oacute;` and so on. Instead use á, ó, ... and encode your script and HTML in UTF-8.

Comment: The max post to return are 4 post in total (3 photos and 1 post with text), in other cases are 2 or 3 @cybmeta

Comment: I believe this issue is similar to this one here
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/ajax-takes-10x-as-long-as-it-should-could?rq=1

Comment: @Karun I think is not the same issue. It is true that you can use the `SHORTINIT` option in ajax calls made through direct PHP script calls; but it doesn't explain why the code of Marcos takes 2 - 3 seconds. Think about it. In a context with high number of ajax requests, using `SHORTINIT` can save a lot of server resources and reduce response time but I think this is not the case and the use or not of SHORTINIT doesn't explain why this ajax action is so slow.

Comment: It is impossible to _guess_ what is slow either. There is nothing inherently _more_ slow in Ajax endpoint that any other WordPress core load.

Comment: Sorry, I had very busy this days.... I changed my code and remove the part to construct my slider but the call to my ajax and this time is 1,6s... I try to insert the code like show me in other question (I put in the question) always send me differents errors @cybmeta

Comment: The manual load of WordPress and `SHORTINIT` method is intended for scripts exectuded outside WordPress where you need to load WordPress manually; for example when the ajax call is made directly to a PHP file outside WordPress. If you use WordPress ajax API, WordPress is already loaded and you get that errors. But this is not related to your question and there are lots of questions and answers about it.