# Understanding SHORTINIT with Wordpress 5

Tags: rest-api, core, constants

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am looking at using Wordpress decoupled, and most tutorials and guides go into detail on using the [Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). Recently, I discovered the `SHORTINIT` option to load a very minimal Wordpress instance. There is next to no documentation, and very few questions about its use, however I am interested in making use of it.

**What have I tried**

So far, I have setup a simple test php file in the root directory:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
//define('DOING_AJAX', true);
define('SHORTINIT', true);

require(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php');

require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php');

die(json_encode(get_posts(array(
   'numberposts' => 10,
   'post_type' => 'post'
))));
```

Which failed because I can't access class WP_Query. After reading a few scattered examples, I gradually added more `require`s but nothing seemed to work.

I have now taken a copy of wp-settings and removed things like `class-wp-rest*.php` or references to the themes. The intention being to leave myself with the absolute minimum core, with enough functionality to obtain the data I need (posts, custom fields). My code now runs, and takes 1/3 of the time to load my posts compared to the `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` endpoint.

**My Question**

I am pre-empting people telling me just to use the REST API, but I would like to know if there is any documentation or examples for creating an endpoint URL which makes use of the `SHORTINIT`, explaining which core components I need.

Comment: Have a look at the wp-settings.php file. `SHORTINIT` is checked on line 134. Look at everything that is loaded after that. The verison of WordPress loaded with `SHORTINIT` is _very_ minimal. It doesn't even load the `WP_Query` class or _any_ of the REST API. So you're missing out on a lot if you do it this way. For example, if you have any plugins that in any way modify post data or change how they're queried or _anything_, then that won't be loaded in your endpoint. So forget querying custom post types.

Comment: `SHORTINIT` is the sort of thing you might use if you just need a handful of utility functions and access to the database object. It's not something you want to use if you're trying to use large chunks of WordPress functionality.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I have looked through `wp-settings.php` and copying that into my test file lets me use get_posts and the like. I want to be able to gradually remove components that I don't need, so that less is loaded and hence gives better performance. Aside from manually removing each `require` by trial and error, I was hoping there would be some sort of guide. Thanks again

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you're over-engineering this. What is the code you actually want to run at your endpoint? How much have you optimised that?

Comment: We've already done a lot with front-end performance, and have had good results with plugins such as WP SuperCache. The next thing to explore is react and the REST API, but I wondered if this method, in certain situations I stress, could be used to give a bit better performance over the API. Also, it's something new so I wanted to have a tinker! Interested to hear if you've used it at all. Totally agree with the over-engineering comment!

Comment: Related to my question, is this old answer by @Rarst https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41812/48962

Answer (score 2):

You could test if the request is coming in through the rest API before enabling the SHORTINIT

Something like...

```php
if (strpos($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-json/') !== false) {
    define('SHORTINIT', true);
}
```